# Why does my Saved image after render has black background instead of transparent, but I already set the Film to Transparent?

Tags: rendering

[image]

[image]

Hello, I need help with this problem. When I render my image the background is transparent, but when I save it, it has a black background. How can I save it without the black background?

Comment: What format are you using to save the render?

Comment: Is it the PNG or JPEG thing? If it's that, I saved it in PNG.

Comment: Yes Emir, it is now fixed, thank you so much. I didn't see that it was a video not an image.